# ReactJs & Material UI: Get input value from a disabled TextField without onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am unable to figure out how I could get pre-populated value from disabled input field. Since the field is disabled onChange won't apply here. Even with inputRef property of TextField, I am able to trigger a function called getNameInputValue and can see the values via console. But when I try to set the state to a function coming via props, I get null errors for value.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
const getNameInputValue = (id, nameValue) => {
  console.log(id, nameValue.value); //works
  props.getNameValues({ ...nameValues, [id]: nameValue.value }) //doesnt work
}

return (
  <Box>
    <Typography>NAME</Typography>
    <TextField
      id={`name-${index}`}
      disabled
      defaultValue={nameValueComingFromTheLoop}
      variant="outlined"
      inputRef={(inputValue) => getNameInputValue(`name-${index}`,inputValue)}
    />
  </Box>
);
```

As requested getNameValues is defined in an outer component, here is its definition:

```
const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState({});

const getNameValues= (receivedNameValuesObj) => {
    setNameValue(receivedNameValuesObj);
  };
```

Comment: fyi, `inputRef` provides you the DoM input field reference, which is equivalent to `getElementById(someId)`, so nameValue is a DoM element.
I am not sure what `getNameValues` do, can you provide more details on this?

Comment: @Harshkurra , added the definition in the question. Basically it just takes in an object in parent component and updates the state there.

Comment: ok, I guess you're keeping an object of `id:value` if yes, then just call `props.getNameValues({ [id]: nameValue.value })`, i mean why do you need to store the DoM element?
second, `setNameValue(receivedNameValuesObj);` at this point you are getting your value or `null`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @christophe No i decided to reuse the values from api call instead. Those disabled fields were getting the values from the same call. However, I wanted to learn how could I grab values in that scenario from disabled inputs.

Comment: Maybe using readOnly instead of disabled.

Comment: @Christophe Will give that a try, thanks. Basically grabbing values based on onChange event makes sense but still how to grab it when its pre-populated in async manner is still not clear.